# asp.net mvc razor vb.net for loop syntax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor

I am new to MVC and razor syntax .Trying to create c#.net code for viewbag but i am not able to find any value of viewbag like the example a `viewbag.Message` and `viewbag.Numtimes`

```
<ul> 
 @for (int i=0; i < ViewBag.NumTimes; i++) { 
  <li>@ViewBag.Message</li> 
 } 
</ul>
```

Comment: You seem to have copied a C# example, you will find a lot of these over VB... you should convert ;)

Answer (score 5):

It's not very different than C#, really. Just using the VB.NET syntax...

```
<ul>
    @For i = 0 To ViewBag.NumTimes-1
        @<li>@ViewBag.Message</li> 
    Next i
</ul>
```

A good reference with many examples is also here:

http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/basics/asp-net-web-pages-visual-basic

**Edit:** Expanded answer a bit and added a link to a nice introduction to VB.NET+Razor

Comment: Thanks guys .I get a runtime error while trying to run the code .Have you tried running the code .FYI-I am using VS2010 .Regards-Pankaj

Comment: Can you tell us what error you get exactly. I didn't try this exact code, but I copied and pasted it from a working version, only changing the names of the variables etc.

Comment: oh, looking at the code again, I think there was a @ missing inside the for loop (before starting the <li>). Since If starts a block, if you want to get out of this block you have to prepend a @. See the new version

Comment: the @ did the charm .Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul> 
 @For i=0 To (ViewBag.NumTimes-1)
  <li>@ViewBag.Message</li> 
 Next i
</ul>
```

For more information see here:

http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/razor_vb_loops.asp

Comment: you beat me to it ;-) Is the ( ) obligatory? I'm having doubts now seeing it in your code.

Comment: @aKzenT I'm not certain to be honest, and can't test at the moment. I always add parentheses when doing math though just so its clear for the program and the developer.

Comment: Thanks guys .I get a runtime error trying to run the code .Have you tried running it ?FYI -I am using VS2010.